# Getting to Run PostgreSQL and Rail on Mac

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pg, rails-postgresql

I am using OSX 10.8 ( looks like some version on Postgres is installed by default ) but still I did these steps one by one and they all succeeded .

```
brew install postgresql
initdb `brew --prefix`/var/postgres -E utf8
touch Gemfile
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=`brew --prefix postgresql`/bin/pg_config
```

And this is a screen shot of the last success message I saw:

[image]

Then I ran this one:

```
postgres -D `brew --prefix`/var/postgres
```

And that's the error I get:

> postgres cannot access the server configuration file
>   "/usr/local/var/postgre/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I think your whole problem is with a short typo.  Compare your error message with what you are doing.  Your error message is:

> postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/ **var/postgre/** postgresql.conf": No such file or directory

Your command is

> postgres -D `brew --prefix`**/var/postgres**

My guess is you are accidently running

```
postgres -D `brew --prefix`/var/postgre
```